# Prolog: Swap two specified index elements in a list error

Tags: list, prolog

As you can see, my algorithm does this weird thing at the end where it's marked red. It does what it's supposed to do, but it reverses all of it afterwards for no reason. I don't understand why it's doing that. Once ListIn is an empty list, there's no reason why the algorithm keeps recurses like that.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide your code as text? I don't want to type your code just to run it.

Comment: Also please describe what your code should be doing and tell us the difference to expected behavior.

Comment: It's supposed to swap two elements of the given two indices in a list. So [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1, 3 results in [3, 2, 1, 4, 5].

Answer (score 2):

When you call a predicate, it will eventually fail or succeed (or loop forever or cause an exception). The calls in the trace you posted are marked `Call`. The failures are marked `Fail`. The successes are marked `Exit`.

In other words, those `Exit` entries are not "doing more work". They mean "returning from work successfully completed".

**Edit:** To add a bit more details, `Call`s and `Exit`s are not shown identically, even if they belong together. A `Call` will typically contain variables (shown by SWI-Prolog as `_123`), and a corresponding `Exit` will often have that variable replaced by some other term. Binding variables to terms is what we do in Prolog to communicate the results of computations.

As a simpler example, consider a definition:

```
hello(world).
```

When we query this with a variable, the result will be a binding of that variable:

```
?- hello(What).
What = world.
```

And here is what this looks like in the debugger:

```
?- trace, hello(What).
   Call: (9) hello(_2014) ? creep
   Exit: (9) hello(world) ? creep
What = world.
```

The `Call` line shows that we call `hello` with a variable as its argument. The `Exit` line shows that that variable was bound to the term `world`. This is not, as you write in your comment, and "exit call" that "does that". This is a **return**, and the state at the point of that return is that the argument variable is bound to `hello`. Again, this is **not another call**.

Note also that calls are nested, so you will often have a series of `Call`s and then the corresponding `Exit`s (which, yet again, are **not calls** but **returns**) in reverse order. If we define:

```
hello(world).

hello2(X) :-
    hello(X).
```

Then we get:

```
?- trace, hello2(What).
   Call: (9) hello2(_390) ? creep
   Call: (10) hello(_390) ? creep
   Exit: (10) hello(world) ? creep
   Exit: (9) hello2(world) ? creep
What = world.
```

So `hello2` is called with a variable. It in turn calls `hello` with that same variable. `hello` binds the variable to `world` and returns (this is the first `Exit` line). `hello2` has nothing more to do and returns as well, in a state where its argument variable is bound to `world` (this is the second `Exit` line).

If you find any of this confusing, don't use this debugger. It *is* confusing. If you think you absolutely need a debugger, see if SWI-Prolog's graphical debugger makes more sense to you: Use `gtrace` instead of `trace` to get into graphical tracing mode. But really, as a beginner you have other things to worry about.

Comment: But you can see it completed to [3,2,1], then turn it into []. I don't understand why the exit calls are doing that.

Comment: I edited my answer, maybe this helps. If it doesn't, please try to minimize your question to something very small, like my examples.

Comment: I can't minimize my example. My example is the question.